# Node Express sending image files as API response

Tags: image, node.js, express

I Googled this but couldn't find an answer but it must be a common problem. This is the same question as [Node request (read image stream - pipe back to response)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004990/node-request-read-image-stream-pipe-back-to-response), which is unanswered.

How do I send an image file as an Express .send() response? I need to map RESTful urls to images - but how do I send the binary file with the right headers? E.g.,

```
<img src='/report/378334e22/e33423222' />
```

Calls...

```
app.get('/report/:chart_id/:user_id', function (req, res) {
     //authenticate user_id, get chart_id obfuscated url
     //send image binary with correct headers
});
```

Comment: How do you retrieve the image server side?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

There is an api in Express.

`res.sendFile`

```
app.get('/report/:chart_id/:user_id', function (req, res) {
    // res.sendFile(filepath);
});
```

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: instead of a file path could you do it from a stream? for instance if you had a variable that you were storing a file in so that you didn't have to actually save the file on the server?

Comment: @BRogers `res` is a writable stream, so if you have a `Buffer` object or a `string` then you can use `.write` method to send it to client.

Comment: Thank you, I will be trying this. I have a CSV buffer that I want to send back to the client and it show as a downloaded file. I'll have to toy with that one. The file isn't very big, so I'm hoping to accomplish this.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Just had to remember to set the `Content-Type`. Thank you!

Comment: res.sendfile is deprecated now, the preferred method is res.sendFile: http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: @BRogers or anybody: Can you pls help me with the writable stream code if you have ? i'm looking for help on downloading different formats(jpg, xls and etc). i've posted my question in forum as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588839/download-all-file-formats-using-angualr-and-express-js. But no luck !!!

Comment: Crucially, it has to be an absolute file path, otherwise you get a (in this context) cryptic `Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided`.

Comment: What if you had multiple images? I'm a little hesitant to use Base64 Encoding.

Answer (score 24):

a proper solution with streams and error handling is below:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const stream = require('stream')

app.get('/report/:chart_id/:user_id',(req, res) => {
  const r = fs.createReadStream('path to file') // or any other way to get a readable stream
  const ps = new stream.PassThrough() // <---- this makes a trick with stream error handling
  stream.pipeline(
   r,
   ps, // <---- this makes a trick with stream error handling
   (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err) // No such file or any other kind of error
      return res.sendStatus(400); 
    }
  })
  ps.pipe(res) // <---- this makes a trick with stream error handling
})
```

with Node older then 10 you will need to use [pump](https://github.com/mafintosh/pump) instead of pipeline.

Comment: I wonder what the real benefit would be here? Because Express `sendFile` does streaming under the hood as well.

Comment: it changes nothing in the simple use case, but let's say you want to do some stream transformation on the fly. Like: zip/unzip a file or decrease the quality o an image on the fly. Those things are simple stream transformations. Did I answer your question?