# download all file formats using angular and express JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm working on downloading all file formats in angular js. With the code piece I have, I can download text formats. But for all the other formats, I am not able to open the downloaded files. My REST service gives response `content-type: application/octet-stream`. My codebase calls res.send(body) method of express.js, with `content-type:application/json`. The downloaded image size is doubled. Also, I could see the type of the body is string.

I am trying to invoke `res.download(path, filename, callback)` function of express.js with `content-type:application/octet-stream` if the request is download call. Is it a correct approach? Also I am not sure which path to send in `res.download` function, as the file comes from the server end. Kindly help me on this.

**my client code:**

```
$scope.downloadFile = function(key) {
  service.downloadFile().then(function(result) {
    var blob = new Blob([result], {
      type: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8'
    });
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;
    var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
    var element = angular.element('<a/>');
    element.attr({
      href: url,
      target: '_blank',
      download: key
    })[0].click();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my colleague shared a link which resolved my problem. There is way to proxy the incoming stream directly. This detail is available in https://github.com/request/request

```
req.pipe(request('url')).pipe(resp)
```

With this the stream can be made available to client and client can invoke the link/url to avail the attached file.

Client code:

```
$scope.downloadFile = function(key) {
   var url = 'http://localhost:8080/getFile';
    var element = angular.element('<a/>');
    element.attr({
      href: url,
      target: '_blank',
      download: fileName
    })[0].click();
  });
}
```