# GET image files from static folder and display them in client app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, feathersjs

I am storing images in a static folder in my express server app. So far this works as expected. The code that matters for this is as follows

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(Path.join(__dirname, `/../uploads`)))
```

Now from the client app, I need to do a GET request on these images and display them, as it stands, just doing a request on my image gives me unusable data which I don't know how to handle. Here is a sample of what I am talking about:

```
IHDRXZ��9�|iCCPICC Profile(�c``*I,(�aa``��+)
rwR���R`������ �`� ��\\��À|����/���J��yӦ�|�6��rV%:���wJjq2#���R��d
```

Is there a way I can get this data and use it as the image?

I have also read up an alternative way of sending images over the wire between the client and server, which would be to set up my GET request. From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515699/node-express-sending-image-files-as-api-response) Basically using express' `.sendFile`, this however does not work as I get a 404 not found. Is there something else wrong?

Anyway, I guess the question is how can I get the files in a format that I can display them on my client app?

This is what my client code looks like:

```
return isomorphicFetch(`${MY_URL}/${imageId}`, {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json'
    }
    method: 'GET'
  })
.then(res => {
    console.log('My fetched image', res)
    return res
 })
```

Comment: The data is not "garbage".

Comment: That was probably a poorly worded, what I mean is that it is unusable data for what I am trying to do, unless of course there is a way of using it.

Comment: Can you include the client-side code at the question?

Comment: Yup. Just updated the OP with the client code

Comment: See [Displaying pdf from arraybuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106584/displaying-pdf-from-arraybuffer). What does `console.log(typeof data)` print? Does `isomorphicFetch` provide the option to set the response type to `ArrayBuffer` or `Blob`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use an `<img>` element?

```js
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = `${MY_URL}/${imageId}`;
someplace.appendChild(img);
```

---

*BTW* if, for some reason, such as sending custom HTTP headers, you want to use `fetch()`:

```js
fetch(`${MY_URL}/${imageId}` /*...*/)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    somewhere.appendChild(img);
  });
```

Comment: Because I am dumb and didn't think of doing that. This works perfectly! Thanks!