# Basic Backend for Image Upload in Angular App

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, rest, express

I am working on an Angular 10 App with Image Upload and couldn´t find anything useful up to now on how to build a Backend for the App, except two articles on Medium for a Java Backend, but that´s not the way I want to go. The app has a Function that saves the Images - this should be connected with an API Call - and in another Component, the Images should be loaded in order to see them in detail, also connected with an API call; I actually thought that building a Backend with Node.js, Express.js and MongoDB would be the way to go here, but I couldn´t find anything useful on the web; so, basically, I am seeking Insights on how to build a very basic REST API for Image Storing and Image Display in an Angular app. Has anyone some useful tipps or hints, maybe? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might I suggest using an upload service like [filestack](https://www.filestack.com/) if you're not already managing an API server or webserver.

Otherwise, if you're already managing a webserver to serve your angular app and assets, just upload them to the webserver and [serve them from the filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63723477/getting-the-image-url-uploaded-in-nodejs). Its [not completely necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) to save them in a databse.